# the map does not display on cordova with leaflet.js

Tags: cordova, leaflet

we have an issue with display map on cordova.we does not have any errors but map is not display.What we do wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm3UC.png)

```
(function () {
"use strict";

document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
    document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);

    var map = L.map('mapid').fitWorld();

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);
}; 

function onPause() {
};

function onResume() {
};
```

})();

Comment: Can you at least display an external image? E.g. if you include an `<img>` tag with `src` to some URL, or `http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/0/0/0.png`?

Answer (score 0):

Image you attached shows that your map script is loading map div - you have zoom in/out buttons. But it looks like it does not load tile layers.

First of all check if you have internet connection on the device/emulator you are testing it. You can add button to your application (`index.html`):

```
<button id="home_network_button"> check network?</button>
```

with this action in `index.js` (it uses jquery, if you don't have it, you can rewrite it to pure javascript):

```
$("#home_network_button").on('click', function(){
    checkConnection();
});

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network';

    alert('Netowrk state: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

---

You can also try to use a different tiles provider in your app, in example Esri (google for others):

```
L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(map);
```

or Mapbox (from Leaflet example):

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(map);
```

---

Also it would useful if you write more details of how you are testing your app. Is it device or some emulator? Are you sure it has internet connection? What version of cordova you are on, for what devices you are compiling the app?